# Intersect tool missing

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have been trying to use the intersect tool, but unexplainably it is not evident on my menu.

[image]

As can been seen in the screen print, the Intersect tool is nowhere to be found. Another user thought that it might be due to me using an old version of Blender - that was my initial thought, but I have since installed 2.78 and the Intersect tool is still in hiding.

Is it possible that I somehow turned it off or hid it im my User Preferences?

Any ideas? Help.

Comment: Select only sphere to intersect from the selection you have selected both cube and sphere. So just select the sphere. Press A then click on 1 vertex of sphere and press L and then go to mesh > faces > intersect

Answer (score 3):

The screen grab on the question shows a project open on v 1.72

[image]

Boolean tools in edit mode were introduced in [version 2.77](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/Modeling).

**Update to a newer version of Blender**

[image]